# Libgdx Changing Textures Sizes

Tags: libgdx, textures

Currently every time I render my background I do this

```
sb.draw(image,position_x,position_y, width, NinjaJumper.V_HEIGHT);
```

I feel like there a a slight lag in my game every once in a while and I read that it might have to do with me drawing the image at a different size than the texture every render.

Is there a way to change the size of the texture in the code? or is there a better way to make it so my texture fits on the screen? I know this method right now might stretch the texture out weirdly but that's something I will handle later.

Comment: many things could be wrong and without any code is difficult to know if this is what is lagging your game

Comment: I realise that, I was just wondering if something like this has caused other people lag cause its the only thing I can think of. I also keep all the other stuff in my render methods as low cost as possible so thats why I think this is the problem. Also does anyone know if it possible to set the size of a texture in the code?

Comment: This wouldn't cause a once-in-a-while lag, because it would be a consistent performance impact on every frame. You might be experiencing lag from the GC. See if you are deallocating anything in your game loop (letting objects go out of scope).

Comment: There isn't anything going out of scope, I set it so that I have to chainshapes as the ground, and once the first chain shape goes off screen, it gets moved infront of the second chain shape and so on.